# How to use Structured Spark Streaming in pySpark to insert row into Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming, pyspark

I am trying to Integrate Kafka with Spark-Structured-Streaming in PySpark to MongoDB Sink. I need help on correcting my code if i am going wrong

Got integrated Kafka-PySpark and PySpark-Mongo. Now trying to integrate the pipeline from Kafka-PySpark-Mongo

I'm using pyspark 2.4.5.

This is my code:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
  .appName("Spark Structured Streaming from Kafka") \
  .getOrCreate()

topic_name = "Be_"

kafka_broker = "localhost:9092"

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers = kafka_broker)

jsonschema = StructType([ \
  StructField("id", StringType()), StructField("Date", StringType()), \
  StructField("Name", StringType()), StructField("Hour", StringType()), \
  StructField("Last_Price", FloatType()), StructField("Var%", FloatType()), \
  StructField("Last_Value", FloatType()), StructField("TYpe", StringType())])

df = spark.readStream.format("kafka") \
          .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_broker) \
          .option("startingOffsets", "latest") \
          .option("subscribe", topic_name) \
          .load() \
          .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)") 

def parse_data_from_kafka_message(sdf, schema):
    from pyspark.sql.functions import split
    assert sdf.isStreaming == True, "DataFrame doesn't receive streaming data"
    col = split(sdf['value'], ',') #split attributes to nested array in one Column
    #now expand col to multiple top-level columns
    for idx, field in enumerate(schema): 
        sdf = sdf.withColumn(field.name, col.getItem(idx).cast(field.dataType))
    return sdf.select([field.name for field in schema])

df= parse_data_from_kafka_message(df, jsonschema)

df \
  .writeStream \
  .format("mongo") \
  .option("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource","mongodb://localhost:27017/DataManagement.Data") \
  .outputMode("append") \
  .start() \
  .awaitTermination()
```

This is the error that comes out in console:

```
I get this error from the console:
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o263.start.
: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Data source mongo does not support streamed writing
```

I also tried using the ForeachWriter:

```
class ForeachWriter:
     def open (self, partition_id, epoch_id):
         # Open connection. This method is optional in Python.
         self.connection = MongoClient ('mongodb: // localhost: 27017')
         self.db = self.connection ['DataManagement']
         self.coll = self.db ['Data']
         pass

     def process (self, row):
         # Write row to connection. This method is NOT optional in Python.
         # Self.coll = None
         self.coll.insert_one (row.asDict ())
         pass

     def close (self, error):
         # Close the connection. This method in optional in Python.
         pass

     df \
         .writeStream \
         .foreach (ForeachWriter ()) \
         .trigger (processingTime = '3 seconds') \
         .outputMode ("Append") \
         .option ("truncate", "false") \
         .start ()
```

Unfortunately the mongodb sink doesn't work either way and I'd like to know if there is another way to send data to MongoDB using PySpark or if I'm doing something wrong in the code. Thank you very much

Comment: Hi, Did you find a solution ?